# ASP.NET - jQuery (document).ready() function is not fired for user control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following jQuery function in my ASP.net user control:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("In Jquery");
        $("[id*=RadioButtonListYesNo]").change(function () {
            alert("In Jquery");
            var res = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

            if (res == '1') {
                $("#divFAFMQues").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#divFAFM").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            else {

                $("#divFAFMQues").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#divFAFM").css("visibility", "visible");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>



</head>
```

The document.ready function is not getting fired when the page containing the user control is getting loaded. Please help.

Comment: did you try writing the same jquery in the page containg your UC ?

Comment: Remove the `src` attribute from the second script tag

Comment: i tried to add it in the page containing UC like the following:<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("In Jquery");

    });
    </script>
</asp:Content> It did not fire, so I tried to add it in the master page head section, still it is not firing.

Comment: when i remove the src attribute from the second tag, it is giving me JS Runtime error: Object Expected. It is only when i add the src tag, the error is not encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please check your jQuery file is importing correctly. Try checking with cdn first.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try to remove `src` element from your 2nd script tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">
```

to

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

complete code:

```
<asp: Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert("In Jquery");
                });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: when i remove the src attribute from the second tag, it is giving me JS Runtime error: Object Expected. It is only when i add the src tag, the error is not encountered.

Comment: working fine for me..please check for syntax errors.

Comment: Thisis what I have written : <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("In Jquery");

    });
    </script>
</asp:Content> Can you please check if there is a difference in what you have written?

Comment: thanks for that, but i am still facing the same problem. i am getting "Object Expected" error at runtime. Should I put some tag like AutoPostBack=true or something like that somewhere?

Comment: there could be other possiblities....1) check if your jQuery is importing successfully. 2) check if you are using __doPostBack

Comment: how can i check if jquery is getting imported successfully or not? I am not using _doPostBack.

Comment: changing the src worked, but i am wondering that it is not a permanent solution for me because my site is intranet site so the script needs to reside in the /Scripts folder, can you please help me in that?

Comment: Good,  as i expected this is a relative path issue.  Make sure the pathpath is correct for your local script file.

Comment: the jquery-1.11.2.js resides under Scripts folder in the Solution Explorer. Hence i am writing ~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js. What should i replace it with so that it gets resolved correctly?

Comment: Are you using jquery 1.11.2 or 1.4.2

Comment: I have both 1.11.2 and 1.4.1 in my Scripts folder. But I cannot access those using ~/Scripts/. Please help.

Comment: Got it, finally it is working with Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js. Thanks for your help and support :)